# Turn project into object oriented

Tags: c#, oop

I worked on a Blackjack game which I created, and I want it to be object oriented.

I first coded it without having that in mind, but I want it to be divided into different classes.
I believe I need to put the methods in various classes and name them appropriately.
The problem is that how do I do this?

I thought it would be as simple as putting "public" in front of every method, but it didn't work.

How do I do this?

If you want my source code, here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace blackJack
{

/// <summary>
/// 'playerCards' will store the player's cards. The maximum of cards a player can hold is 11.
/// 'hitOrStand' asks the player if they want to hit or stand.
/// 
/// 'score' cardCounts the player's score for that round.
/// 'cardCount' increases so that the player can hold multiple cards in their hand.
/// 'scoreDealer' cardCounts the dealer's score for that round.
/// 
/// 'newCard' works to randomize the player's cards.
/// </summary>

class Program
{
    static Random newCard = new Random();
    static int score = 0, cardCount = 1, scoreDealer = 0;
    static string[] playerCards = new string[11];
    static string hitOrStand = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// MAIN METHOD
    /// 
    /// The Main method starts the game by executing 'Start()'
    /// </summary>

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// START METHOD
    /// 
    /// The Start method lets the player know that they are playing Blackjack.
    /// Then it deals the player two cards (because in Blackjack, you start with two cards).
    /// It tells the player what their score score is at that moment.
    /// Finally, it asks the player if they want to hit (continue and get a new card), or stand (stop) through the Game() method (which lies below this).
    /// </summary>

    static void Start()
    {
        scoreDealer = newCard.Next(15, 22);
        playerCards[0] = Deal();
        playerCards[1] = Deal();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome! The dealer gives you " + playerCards[0] + " and " + playerCards[1] + ". \nScore: " + score + ".\nWould you like to hit or stand?");
            hitOrStand = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        } while (!hitOrStand.Equals("hit") && !hitOrStand.Equals("stand"));
        Game();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// GAME METHOD
    /// 
    /// The Game method checks if the player did hit or if the player did stand.
    /// If the player did hit, that method (the Hit method) is executed.
    /// But if the player did stand, it checks if their score is larger than the dealer's AND if the score equals/less than 21.
    /// If the above statement is TRUE, it will congratulate, and reveal the dealer's score. Then it'll ask if the player wants to play again.
    /// 
    /// However, if the above is FALSE, it will tell the player that they lost, reveal the dealer's score, and ask if the player wants to play again.
    /// </summary>

    static void Game()
    {
        if (hitOrStand.Equals("hit"))
        {
            Hit();
        }
        else if (hitOrStand.Equals("stand"))
        {
            if (score > scoreDealer && score <= 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nCongratulations! You won! The dealer's score was " + scoreDealer + ".\nWould you like to play again? y/n");
                PlayAgain();
            }
            else if (score < scoreDealer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou lost! The dealer's score was " + scoreDealer + ".\nWould you like to play again? y/n");
                PlayAgain();
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DEAL METHOD
    /// 
    /// The Deal method creates a random number between 1 and 14.
    /// Then that int switches and assigns a value to Card.
    /// Depending on its result, it will add to the amount on score.
    /// Lastly, it'll return the string Card.
    /// 
    /// Below, all the cards that are available can be viewed.
    /// </summary>

    static string Deal()
    {
        string Card = "";
        int cards = newCard.Next(1, 14);
        switch (cards)
        {
            case 1: Card = "2"; score += 2;
                break;
            case 2: Card = "3"; score += 3;
                break;
            case 3: Card = "4"; score += 4;
                break;
            case 4: Card = "5"; score += 5;
                break;
            case 5: Card = "6"; score += 6;
                break;
            case 6: Card = "7"; score += 7;
                break;
            case 7: Card = "8"; score += 8;
                break;
            case 8: Card = "9"; score += 9;
                break;
            case 9: Card = "10"; score += 10;
                break;
            case 10: Card = "Jack"; score += 10;
                break;
            case 11: Card = "Queen"; score += 10;
                break;
            case 12: Card = "King"; score += 10;
                break;
            case 13: Card = "Ace"; score += 11;
                break;
            default: Card = "2"; score += 2;
                break;
        }
        return Card;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// HIT METHOD
    /// 
    /// The Hit method adds another card to the player's hand, as they demanded (when they decided to hit instead of stand).
    /// Then it checks if the player still holds an amount less than 21, got Blackjack (21), or Busted (received an amount over 21).
    /// 
    /// If the amount is less than 21, the player may continue, and they will be asked if they'd like to hit or stand.
    /// </summary>

    static void Hit()
    {
        cardCount += 1;
        playerCards[cardCount] = Deal();
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou were dealed a " + playerCards[cardCount] + ".\nYour new score is " + score + ".");
        if (score.Equals(21))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nBlackjack! Congratulations! The dealer's score was " + scoreDealer + ".\nWould you like to play again? y/n");
            PlayAgain();
        }
        else if (score > 21)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou busted, and lost. The dealer's score was " + scoreDealer + ".\nWould you like to play again? y/n");
            PlayAgain();
        }
        else if (score < 21)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nWould you like to hit or stand?");
                hitOrStand = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            } while (!hitOrStand.Equals("hit") && !hitOrStand.Equals("stand"));
            Game();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// PLAYAGAIN METHOD
    /// 
    /// This method simply asks the player if they want to play again, or not.
    /// If the player replies with a 'y', it will tell the player to press enter in order to restart the game.
    /// 
    /// If the player replies with an 'n', it will tell the player to press enter in order to close the game.
    /// </summary>

    static void PlayAgain()
    {
        string playAgain = "";
        do
        {
            playAgain = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        } while (!playAgain.Equals("y") && !playAgain.Equals("n"));
        if (playAgain.Equals("y"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to play again.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            scoreDealer = 0;
            cardCount = 1;
            score = 0;
            Start();
        }
        else if (playAgain.Equals("n"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThank you for playing. \nPress Enter to close the game.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You could start by making proper cards. You could have a `Card` class that has `Properties` like `Suit` and `Value`.  Then you could have a `Deck` class that holds all the cards and provides `Methods` like `Shuffle` which randomizes the cards.  Think about the objects involved in any card game and think about what properties those objects have and what they should be able to do or what you might want to do with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conceptual approach to the term "Object-Oriented" is to tackle a code problem with, from my point of view, a view as close to reality as possible.

What I meant by that is, if you would have to create the behavior of a car, you would encapsulate all the variables and functions related to that "object" inside a class, so that when you would instantiate it, you would in effect create an `object` "car" inside the computer that would react the same way a real object would.

Hierarchy between classes come from the same concept. We know a car is a vehicle, but you know you cannot create a vehicle because it's an abstract concept. Variables and functions that are general to all vehicle should be inside that `abstract` class, from which every other car/bike/truck derive from.

In case of a card game, each card could become an object, that would contain a reference towards their visual. So, you would get a `List<Card>` allowing you to easily pick, remove or add one. The table could be an object too, that contain position/id of the players and where the cards go when distributed.

But direct "object" approach is not always possible, as in real life, there is no such thing as a "Game" object that contains rules and overview the steps of the game. But once you understand the concept being OO Programming, you would see that it's basically how and where you put your variables and your functions, and how polymorphism and a clean structure make for much easier to read and maintain code.

OO Programming is not such an easy term to understand, and when people start mixing philosophy with it, it just get harder for no reason. I actually give a 4 hours class as introduction to this notion, so don't expect to catch all of it in minutes. At first, just try putting the stuff where they sound the most logical place to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic steps;

1) Right click on the project/solution and select Add->Class
2) Name the class appropriately like `Game` for the game.
3) Move methods like `Deal()` into this class and declare them as `Public Deal()` (or private when it's appropriate, obviously it isn't for Deal).
4) In your main create a game instance with `Game game = new Game();`
5) Call the methods with the dot operator ie `game.Deal();` to deal the game.